# php javascript echo javascript variable to php loop condition dynamically using onclick or how can I use ajax to solve it?

Tags: javascript, php

How can I store only the value of f() into `$ab`?
How can I also change $ab dynamically in the loop condition when the button is pressed so that the integers are printed out dynamically?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;
function f(){
i = i + 10;
document.getElementById("more").innerHTML= i;
}
</script>
```

php

```
$ab = "<p id='more'> </p>";
echo $ab;
for($x=0;$x<$ab;$x++) echo $x . "<br>";
echo "<button type='button' onclick='f()'> > </button>";
```

Comment: wat are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to print out the integers from 0 to 19 when the button is pressed once and  from 0 to 29 when the button is pressed twice and so on.
I just simplify my original question into this question.

Comment: once website is loaded thats it you can only work with javascript hence client and server side processing unless you use ajax to communicate with server, please change the question and provide more information on what you are trying to do perhaps then someone can help you

Comment: tomhre, I do not have experience on using ajax. How can I use ajax to solve the problem?

Comment: Another approach. Output the first (0-9) using `PHP`. Put these numbers in a `<span> or <div>` with a name/id so you can select them using javascript. Change your `$ab` to "<p id='more' name='0'>" . On click send the value of name then in javascript, use `i=name value`, adjust the numbers, adjust the name to 10.

Comment: RST, I love your approach. Would you mind to write the code to answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Hope this work for you.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 10;
    function f(){
        i = i + 10;
        var html = "";
        for(var j=0;j<i;j++){
            html += j+"<br/>";
        }
        document.getElementById("more").innerHTML= html;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I have used this trick before. But, I also want to display from 0 to 9 without clicking the button. So, I have to write some php code for both with and without clicking the button. As my original code is quite long, the code becomes more and complex. If there are no simple solutions, I will use this again as the last resort.

Comment: I didn't get your point.
What out put you want can you please attache screen shot?

Comment: your code is the output I want. But, if I also want to display from 0 to 9 without clicking the button, there is another code I need to put. I don't want to put the redundant code.

Comment: You can use jquery trigger if you dont want to click on button.
trigger click on dom ready

Answer (score -1):

You need to send the variable `$x` to your function `f`

```
echo "<button type='button' onclick='f($x)'> > </button>";
```

Then in the function you can count how many times the buttons all together are clicked, `i++`:

```
var i = 0;
function f(x) {
  x += i * 10;
  i++;
  document.getElementById("more").innerHTML= i;
}
```